Code commit shows conflicts when try o merge dev branch to stg branch
I am trying to merge Dev branch into Staging branch using Visual Studio but it shows me conflicts. When I see the list of conflicts it shows me dlls, and sever files checked out which were not even changed.
And when i try to undo those files, it shows me Permission Denied message. Screenshots Attached below:




